# Internship in Netherlands

Tags: visa, netherlands, employment, internship

I have received interest from a Dutch company in the Netherlands that wishes to hire me as an Intern. The company is in civil engineering research and development.

I am not a student and a non-EU citizen. My prospective employer has informed me that this would not entitle me  to an [internship under normal Dutch regulations.](http://www.visaversa.com/en/netherlands/dutch-work-visa/internship/)

What other construct can I use in this case? The salary is way low as this is an internship (probably below minimum wage). I am however very interested in this company and they have asked me to do some research beforehand. I have seen one for "Highly Skilled Worker" in the ind.nl website but this category has minimum wage requirements which I probably won't fit into.

Comment: Don't do any research for them beforehand! If they really want your work, tell them to raise the salary so you qualify under highly skilled worker or some other visa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, options seem to be:

1. Internship - but that requires you to be enrolled in some kind of academic/study program. Here's a [site](http://businessculture.org/western-europe/business-culture-in-netherlands/internship-and-placement-in-netherlands/) with a bit more information and links.
2. Direct employment ("highly-skilled" migrant is not as highly skilled as you might think. Check the exact criteria.)
3. Employment in your home country, so that your stay in the Netherlands would officially be a visit - but you'll need to check how long you can stay here with that status
4. You becoming a freelance consultant with them contracting you. I'm not sure if that's far-fetched or practical, but it [is an option](http://www.businesslegalconsultancy.com/en/3204/self-employed-residence-permit-in-the-netherlands-holland-ind.html) which can grant you temporary residence here.

Caveat Emptor: I'm not that well-versed in Dutch immigration law.

**Edit:** I found [this](https://www.hollandalumni.nl/career/files/practicalities/quick-guide-hiring-an-intl-intern) table, which suggests it's possible for an employer to apply on your behalf for, well, I guess it's sort of a work+residence visa specifically for the case of an internship.